# Mongoid's demongoize method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb

I'm building web service using MongoDB. Everyhing works except one thing. I got an error:
[image]

My demongoize method:

```
def self.demongoize obj
case obj
 when nil then nil
 when {} then Address.new
 when Hash then Address.new(obj[:city], obj[:state], Point.new(obj[:loc][:coordinates][0], obj[:loc][:coordinates][1])) if obj[:city]&&obj[:state]&&obj[:loc]
 when Address then obj
 else nil
 end
 end
```

It seems to me demongoize nil returns nil, and later in my views there is entrant.city. So I added some logic:

```
 <tbody>
    <% @entrants.each do |entrant| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= entrant.overall_place %></td>
        <td><%= format_hours entrant.secs %></td>
        <% if entrant.racer.id %>
          <td><%= link_to "#{entrant.last_name}, #{entrant.first_name}", racer_path(entrant.racer.id) %></td>
        <% else %>
          <td><%= "#{entrant.last_name}, #{entrant.first_name}" %></td>
        <% end %>

        <td><%= entrant.bib %></td>
        <% if entrant.city %>
        <td><%= entrant.city %></td>
         <% else %>
         <td><%= nil %></td>
         <% end %>
        <% if entrant.state %>
        <td><%= entrant.state %></td>
         <% else %>
         <td><%= nil %></td>
         <% end %>
         ...
```

But I'm still getting the same error. I'll appreciate any help.

Comment: could you please paste track logs from termincal

Comment: sure, but what do you mean by track logs? :) Screenshot shows output of Rspec test checking for expect(cells[4].text).to eql c_entrant.city